# How can I give my Cloud Run (managed) Application access to my GKE Cluster services?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

### Story

I have a GKE Cluster running and in there some pods and their services.
At the moment I trigger one of those services by a given url `http://myapp/start?foo=1&bar=2`
So since I am tired of executing this endpoint by hand or whatever tool available I started to build my own webapp so execute this endpoint.

Since I only need this webapp occassionally - I want to deploy it via Cloud Run (fully managed) so it only spins up when needed.

### Here comes my question

The webapp in Cloud Run has no access to the GKE Services. This makes it somehow useless for me. How can Cloud Run be integrated into the GKE Cluster network **without** deploying it there? I really want to extract this app from the resources I use in the GKE Cluster.
I feel that this feature is not yet implemented for Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to integrate Cloud Run fully managed services to a GKE Cluster.

As you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/choosing-a-platform), the fully managed cloud run services have no access to VPC / Compute Engine Network. Also as it's mentioned on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVdhyprptTQ), only Cloud Run on GKE clusters are able to access other resources within the virtual network. Also on the video it is stated that this is on the road map for fully managed Cloud Run, so it might be implemented soon.

I hope this information helped you.

Comment: yes it does thanks. Then I have to open an ingress with cloud armor ip restriction and give it access to it :shrug: